# Using CTRL key to select mulitple rows to drag drop from one datagrid to another datagrid in silveright 4

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I have silverlight application developed in Silverlight Version: 4.0.60531.0. In one page i have 2 datagrids. I have enabled DataGridDragDropTarget for both the datagrids.

If i use CTRL key to select random rows and drag drop, it wouldn't work. Please let me know what i'm missing in below xaml. Thanks in advance.

Below 2 scenarios it is working fine.

1. Drag one row at a time
2. Using SHIFT key and selecting multiple rows,it is working fine.

```xml
    xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"
    xmlns:tk="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data.Toolkit"

    <tk:DataGridDragDropTarget   AllowDrop="True" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" > 
        <sdk:DataGrid  x:Name="d1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Extended"> 
            <sdk:DataGrid.Columns> 
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Number"  IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=No}" /> 
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Name"  IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Name}" /> 
            </sdk:DataGrid.Columns> 
        </sdk:DataGrid> 
    </tk:DataGridDragDropTarget>


    <tk:DataGridDragDropTarget  AllowDrop="True" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" > 
        <sdk:DataGrid  x:Name="d2" Height="100" Grid.Row="1" SelectionMode="Extended" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"> 
            <sdk:DataGrid.Columns> 
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Number"  IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=No}" /> 
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Name"  IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Name}" /> 
            </sdk:DataGrid.Columns> 
        </sdk:DataGrid> 
    </tk:DataGridDragDropTarget>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't so much multiple selection using the Ctrl key.  If you release the Ctrl key during the drag-and-drop operation, you should find that the drag-and-drop operation completes successfully.  It's more to do with dropping the items with Ctrl held down.  Apparently, this indicates that you want to copy the items instead of move them.

I don't know of any documentation to back me up on this, but I did find the following in a documentation comment on an internal class ([Microsoft.Windows.DragOperation](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/61620#779732), method GetDragDropEffects):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the allowed effects by analyzing the state of the keys 
    /// pressed.  If the control key is pressed the user is requesting a 
    /// copy. If copy is available the effect will be only copy, if not 
    /// available the effect will be None.
    /// </summary>
```

I added the property `AllowedSourceEffects="Copy"`  to both of your DataGridDragDropTargets, and then I found that the drag-and-drop functionality stopped working altogether.  However, when I changed these properties to `AllowedSourceEffects="Copy,Move"`, I found that drag-and-drop worked again, including when I held the Ctrl key down.  However, even when I held the Ctrl key down, the items were moved instead of copied.

Comment: By defualt it is move when we drag and drop and that is what i wanted. With the same above code CTRL key is also working. The trick is when u move the items to the destination first you release the CTRL key and then your Mouse LButton. But this is not the case with SHIFT key. Looks like either SHIFT key or Mouse LButton can be released first. Thanks Luke.